# Вставка результата POST запроса через JS

Tags: html, javascript

У меня есть таблица:

```
    <table style="width: 100%; border-spacing:0px;">
     <tr>
      <td onclick="">№</td>
      <td onclick="">Предмет</td>
      <td onclick="">Бренд</td>
      <td onclick="">Артикул</td>
      <td onclick="">Размеры</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td onclick="">№</td>
      <td onclick="">Предмет</td>
      <td onclick="">Бренд</td>
      <td onclick="">Артикул</td>
      <td onclick="">Размеры</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td onclick="">№</td>
      <td onclick="">Предмет</td>
      <td onclick="">Бренд</td>
      <td onclick="">Артикул</td>
      <td onclick="">Размеры</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td onclick="">№</td>
      <td onclick="">Предмет</td>
      <td onclick="">Бренд</td>
      <td onclick="">Артикул</td>
      <td onclick="">Размеры</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

После ввода юзером в некое поле цифр, идет отправка POST запроса в файл, который возвращает новое тело таблицы "все, кроме первой строки "заголовка" таблицы". Стоит вопрос: как все содержимое таблицы заменять на результат запроса?

Ps: вид запроса прост:

```
$('.mini_search').keyup(function() {
  var keywords = $(this).val();
  var type = $(this).attr('types');
  $.post("/system/search/mini.php", { keywords: keywords , type:type}, function(data){
   $('.result').html(data);
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Введите элемент `tbody` и дайте ему id. И уже в `$(tbody).html(text);` вставляете что пришло.